# Error: Unable to upload application to Magento Cloud

Tags: magento2, deploy, magento-cloud, devops

When I try to push a new code to my Magento Cloud instance I get this error below, it doesn't matter which version, even a version that worked previously.

[image: Error: Unable to upload application to Magento Cloud]

How could I find the issues?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably happening because of the disk space, to make sure of it, run this command below in your Magento Cloud instance.

```
df -h | grep data
```